# What is the difference between @app.route and @app.get in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

What is the difference between these snippets?

```
@app.route("/greeting")
def greet():
    return "Hello World"
```

And

```
@app.get("/greeting")
def greet():
    return "Hello World"
```

They have the same result.

I'm familiar with `@app.route()` but I can't find any documentation for `@app.get`

Comment: No difference, given that the default for [`route`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=get#flask.Flask.route) is `methods=["GET"]` and [`get`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=get#flask.Flask.get) is just a shortcut for the same thing. I'd argue `app.get` is more intent-revealing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoted from [the changelog](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/changes/) for Flask 2.0:

> Add route decorators for common HTTP methods. For example, `@app.post("/login")` is a shortcut for `@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])` [#3907](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/3907).

In your case,

```
@app.get("/greeting")
```

is equivalent to

```
@app.route("/greeting", methods=["GET"])
```

And since `["GET"]` is the default, this is equivalent to

```
@app.route("/greeting")
```

[Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=app%20get#flask.Flask.get) is the documentation for `@app.get`.